# extjs select record from first grid and copy the selected to second grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

now I have 2 grid panels. I want to select the some records of the first grid by using getselectionmodel() and the selected records will be load to the second grid and recreate a new grid.

are there any ways can load the selected records into second grid store?

I am using extjs3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call [[your first grid]].getSelectionModel().getSelections(), it will return an array of records

then you need to convert this array of records to a second array, let's call it data,  readable by the reader of the second store.

So suppose your second store is an Ext.data.ArrayStore

```
var store2 = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
            fields: [   { name: 'field1' }, { name: 'field2' }  ]
        });
```

your convert function will be

```
function convert(records){
   var record;
   var data = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
        record = records[i];
        data.push([record.get('your field'), record.get('another field')]);
    }
    return data;
}
```

then on the second grid you can call .getStore().loadData(data)